# Concatenating strings in requestScope

Tags: jsp, jstl, concatenation, el

My requirement is to concatenate string at the end of the requestScope variable . ex requestScope.value[bean.selected_value] where bean.selected_value is the value to be concatenated during looping and the value changes based on selection.here is my code

```
<select class="formtext">
    <option value="">Select month</option>
    <c:set var="monthsCollection" value='${requestScope.Month + '_' + [bean.selectedvalue}' />      
    <c:if test="${!empty monthsCollection}">
    <c:forEach var="monthList" items="${monthsCollection}">
        <option value="<c:out value='${monthList}' />"
        <c:out value='${stationList}' />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</select>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate strings in an expression. The `+` operator can only be used on numbers. What you can do is using two expressions in the `value` attribute of `<c:set/>`:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="${var1}${var2}"/>
```

So, in your case you should use:

```
<c:set var="monthsCollectionVarName" value="Month${bean.selectedvalue}" />
<c:set var="monthsCollection" value="${requestScope[monthsCollectionVarName]}" />
```